# percentage div size wrong in firefox

Tags: css, html

I have created a homepage that works perfectly in chrome, and I am testing in firefox and it appears some div boxes are using my main content div to work out their percentage height and width as opposed to their direct parent. Thus, the divs are much larger than they should be.

I am trying to get a fiddle to work, but have been unsuccessful, it looks even more random!
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/Y468X/)

To confirm the problem, the following divs (runner, runnerBtmLeft runnerBtmRight and runnerRight) are using div main_content to calculate their percentage size, whereas they should (and do in chrome) use their direct parent (container). At least this is what I can work out is happening, as I have used background colors to work out where firefox thinks each div starts and ends.

Is there a way to ensure the divs runner, runnerBtmLeft runnerBtmRight and runnerRight use their parent div container to calculate their percentage sizes?

Here is the necessary code ;

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <!--header and linkbar go here-->

<div class="outerContainer">
<div class="container">
  <div class="runner">
  </div>
  <div class="runnerRight">
  <h1>Get Involved!</h1>
  <p>Find out more about Eastbourne Netball League, and how you can be a part of it.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="runnerBtmLeft">
  <h1>Latest News</h1>
  <p>Read all about it, the latest news, upcoming events and courses</p>
  </div>
  <div class="runnerBtmRight">
  <div class="textBox">
  <p>Tables and Results</p>
  </div>
  <img src="pic5.png">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btmBanner">
  <h1>Team Directory</h1>
  <p>Club contact info, player lists and training info</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="speech">
<img src="quotesLeft.png" id="left">
<img src="quotesRight.png" id="right">
<p>Who doesn't love a good game of netball, eh&#63; </p>

</div>
</div>
<footer id="mainFooter">
<!--footer info here-->
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS...

```
runnerRight{width:49.5% ; height: 49.5%; position: absolute ; right:0 ; top: 0 ; 
display: inline-block ; border-radius: 40pt ; -
webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey}

.runnerRight {background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient
(bottom left, #D0A9F5 10%, #BE81F7 100%) ; 
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, #D0A9F5 10%, #BE81F7 100%) ;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom left, #D0A9F5 10%, #BE81F7 100%)} 

.runnerRight h1 {text-align:center ; color:white ; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #A4A4A4 
; font-size: 44pt ; font-family: century gothic, sans-serif}
.runnerRight p {text-align:center ; font-size: 20pt ; 
font-family: century gothic, sans-serif} 

.runnerBtmLeft{width:49.5% ; height: 49.5%; position: absolute ; left:0 ; bottom: 0 ; 
display: inline-block ; border-radius: 40pt ; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey}

.runnerBtmLeft {background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient
(bottom left, #D0A9F5 10%,#BE81F7 100%) ; 
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, #D0A9F5 10%, #BE81F7 100%) ;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom left, #D0A9F5 10%, #BE81F7 100%)} 

.runnerBtmLeft h1 {text-align:center ; color:white ; 
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #A4A4A4 ;font-size: 44pt ; 
font-family: century gothic, sans-serif}
.runnerBtmLeft p {text-align:center ; font-size: 20pt ; 
font-family: century gothic,     sans-serif} 

.runnerBtmRight {position: absolute ; bottom:0 ; right: 0 ; 
width: 49.5% ; height: 49.5% ; border-radius: 40pt ; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 

-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
overflow:hidden ; background: white}
.runnerBtmRight img {position: absolute ; top: 13%}

.runnerBtmRight .textBox {background: black ; width: 100% ; 
height: 20% ; overflow: hidden ; position: absolute ; bottom: 0 ; 
opacity: 0.7}
.runnerBtmRight .textBox p {color: white ; text-align:center ; 
font-size: 20pt ; font-family: century gothic, sans-serif} 

.outerContainer .btmBanner {width:998px ; height: 197px ; 
position:relative ; bottom:1em ;  background:purple ; opacity: 0.4 ; 
color:white ; text-align:center ; border-radius: 40pt}
.outerContainer .btmBanner h1 {padding-top:0.8em ; font-size: 28pt ; 
font-family:century gothic, sans-serif}
.outerContainer .btmBanner p {font-size:20pt ; 
font-family: century gothic, sans-serif}

footer#mainFooter {padding-bottom: 2em ; padding-top: 0.5em ; 
text-align:center ; background:black ; opacity: 0.7 ; color: white ; 
width: 100% ; margin-top: 20em ; position:     
relative ; bottom: 0 ; font-family: century gothic, sans-serif}
footer#mainFooter h1 {font-size:20pt}
footer#mainFooter p {font-size: 14pt}

.speech {margin-left:10% ; margin-right: auto ;  
width:40% ; height: 100% ; position:relative}
.speech p {text-align:center ; padding:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 1.5em ; 
color:navy ; font-size: 26pt ; font-family: century gothic, sans-serif }
.speech #left  {position: absolute ; top:0.5em ; left:0.5em}
.speech #right {position: absolute ; bottom: 0.5em ; right: 0.5em}
```

Comment: Man, your code and your indentation is really messy.

Comment: @MrLister I think it has no intention, it's messy. I removed it from the example to have a fiddle working. http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/Y468X/

Comment: if your browser is not up to date then that may be the cause of some anomalies try updating it.I use an updated version of firefox and the percentage widths are all looking like they are supposed to

Comment: It's completely broken in Chrome/Mac.

Comment: ok i'll give that a go, thanks. However, I can't rely on other people to have the updated versions, is there a way around this? thanks

Comment: no not that im aware of.you can try googling it or you could tell them to update their browser for optimal performance when they view your page

Comment: I see errors like a `-` on the end of the line and `webkit-box-shadow` on the next. What happens if you correct those?

Comment: i just checked and do have to latest firefox version, it is still wrong. I'll try and upload a screenshot, though I can't work it out at the minute

Comment: runnerRight is specified twice, once with a correct .runnerRight selector, once with a bad selector runnerRight. You can remove it has I  guess it has no goals.

Comment: try using a pixel width instead of a precentage width.if i were you i would avoid using too many precentage width divs

Comment: ok great, i've used pixels and the divs are now the correct size. however, they are still poisition at the far corners of my main content div as opposed to the container div!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Adding position: relative to container divs, along with changing from percentage to pixels worked perfectly. However, I imagine had I changed the position: relative first, I may not have needed to change to pixels